# More information in questions listings wanted

Tags: feature-request

I'd like to have more information in questions listings about each question, and about the reason for its appearance in the list: instead of a generic "modified", we could have "asked", "question edited", "answered", "answer edited"...

What we have now (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/?tagnames=haskell&sort=active):

[image]

What I would like:

[image]

I did a quick search on this meta and found no relevant questions.